# Indirect Speech/whether-if

Tags: indirect-speech, whether

We say:
I don't know whether he is right.

Is it acceptable to say:
I don't know he's right or wrong.

Comment: You can say: I don't know (that) he is right. I don't know he is British. I don't know he wants it. But the meaning will be that of assertion, rather than doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You should say, "I don't know **if** he's right or wrong."

Comment: You mean "I don't know he's right or wrong." is never said, not even in spoken English?

Comment: Correct. We always say it like: "I don't know if he's right or wrong" or "I don't know whether he is right or wrong."

Answer (score 1):

We use "**if**" or **"whether"** to introduce clauses after verbs of ***doubting***:

I don’t know if I can drive. My foot really hurts.

Look at [If or whether: indirect questions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) at the Cambridge Dictionary.

> I don't know whether he is right or not
>
> I don't know whether he is right or wrong

Comment: Already know that. Just wanted to know if it's ever said in spoken English!

Comment: I don't think it is correct. If you google it there is no result except what is written on this page. But, "I don't know if he's right or wrong" appears 52,000 times!